# Java interface for stack operations

Tags: java, data-structures, interface, stack

I have in mind a method that takes as an argument a collection that supports just the stack operations `push` and `pop`. What is the most appropriate interface for this?

```
public void foo(WhatShouldThisTypeBe<String> stack) {
    stack.push(bar());
    ...;
    String xyz = stack.pop();
}
```

My thoughts are:

1. I could make my method take a `java.util.Stack` but that is a legacy class, with unwanted synchronization overhead, and shouldn't be used in 2023.
2. I could make it take a `List` (which supports the equivalent operations `addLast()` and `removeLast()`) but that would put unnecessary demands on the concrete type, such as the ability to take the nth element.
3. I could make it take a `Deque` but again that would put unnecessary demands on the concrete type, such as support for the Queue operations `add` and `remove` which are not required.

Is there a Java interface that suits stack operations more precisely than any of the above?

Comment: Here is the _JavaDoc_ entry, for _[The Collections Framework (Java SE 21 & JDK 21)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/doc-files/coll-index.html#the-collections-framework-heading)_.  And, here is the _Java_ tutorial, regarding,   _[Trail: Collections (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)_.

Comment: Tip: [*Eclipse Collections*](https://eclipse.dev/collections/) offers interfaces and implementations for stacks, including methods for `push`, `pop`, and `peek`. See [`MutableStack`](https://eclipse.dev/collections/javadoc/11.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/stack/MutableStack.html). Perhaps *Google Guava* has something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) probably steers closest to what you're looking for; it has the obvious downside of not existing prior to JDK21, at which point `Deque` is probably the closest you want, but, as you found, it adds a little too much.

Crucially for you, `ArrayList` **does** implement `SequencedCollection`.

Failing all these things, there really is no option. You're presumably looking for some type that both `ArrayDeque` as well as `ArrayList` implement, as 2 somewhat arbitrarily chosen types that can trivially support fast 'add at end' and 'remove last' operations which is all you really need. The only one that is halfway relevant is `Collection`, but it does not offer 'remove from end', thus, cannot be used here.

Hence, if requiring JDK21 isn't an option, then you're either stuck making multiple methods (one that takes any `Deque`, one that takes an `ArrayList` for example), making wrappers (make your own interface, then write methods that wrap types well known to support it into an object that implements this interface):

```
public interface Stackish<E> {
  void push(E elem);
  E pop() throws NoSuchElementException;

  public static <E> Stackish<E> of(ArrayList<E> list) {
    return new Stackish<E>() {
      @Override public void push(E elem) {
        list.add(elem);
      }

      @Override public E pop() throws NoSuchElementException {
        try {
          return list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    };
  }
}
```

This would have the rather obvious annoying factor that users of your library need to wrap their collections.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Answer by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77572929/642706), the [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) interface implemented by `List` and [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) in Java 21+ makes creating your own `Stack` class a bit easier.

Here is some rough initial code as a proof-of-concept. Caveat: I am not an expert on [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).

First the interface.

```java
public interface Stack < T >
{
    public void push ( T element );

    public T pop ( );

    public T peek ( );
}
```

And an implementation. Not thread-safe. Not thoroughly tested.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

// Initial implementation of a stack.
// Not thread-safe.
// Uses `SequencedCollection` methods in Java 21+.
public class StackArray < T > implements Stack < T >
{
    private final ArrayList < T > list = new ArrayList <> ( );

    @Override
    public void push ( final T element )
    {
        this.list.add ( element );
    }

    public T peek ( )
    {
        if ( this.list.isEmpty ( ) ) return null;
        return this.list.getLast ( );
    }

    @Override
    public T pop ( )
    {
        if ( this.list.isEmpty ( ) ) return null;
        return this.list.removeLast ( );
    }

    // `Object` overrides.

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "StackArray{" + list + '}';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    Stack < String > stack = new StackArray <> ( );
    String nothing = stack.peek ( );
    System.out.println ( "nothing = " + nothing );

    stack.push ( "Alice" );
    stack.push ( "Bob" );
    String bob = stack.peek ( );
    System.out.println ( "bob = " + bob );

    stack.push ( "Carol" );
    System.out.println ( "stack = " + stack );

    String carol = stack.pop ( );
    System.out.println ( "carol = " + carol );
    System.out.println ( "stack = " + stack );

    String bob2 = stack.pop ( );
    System.out.println ( "bob2 = " + bob2 );

    System.out.println ( "stack = " + stack );
```

When run:

```
nothing = null
bob = Bob
stack = StackArray{[Alice, Bob, Carol]}
carol = Carol
stack = StackArray{[Alice, Bob]}
bob2 = Bob
stack = StackArray{[Alice]}
```